# Can Google Calendar view six weeks, not starting at the beginning of a month?

Tags: google-calendar

Google Calendar's month view can display up to six weeks, by clicking on the first week of the month (on the small calendar on the sidebar) and dragging the month downwards towards the last week of the month. This however limits this view to a 6-week period starting at the beginning of any month (and furthermore, scrolling up or down jumps six weeks at a time).

What if I want to view the six weeks between September 4th and October 15th, 2011 (assuming Sunday is the first day of the week)?

Is this possible (via the UI, to begin with)?

Then, for extra credit: one can create a link to Google Calendar, which goes straight to a certain month in the month view, e.g.:

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?mode=month&date=20110901

However, no matter what day in September one specifies, the displayed Calendar still starts in September's first week.

Can a link be created to view six weeks?

Can a link be created to a calendar that starts in the middle of the month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are making the selection of weeks to show in the mini calendar, you can actually change the month with the mouse wheel while you click and drag (if the cursor is stopped while you use the mouse wheel, it may require moving to another day to pick the new month). This lets you create a calendar view several months long.

Comment: Any way to do this if you have no mouse wheel? (Laptop with no mouse.)

Comment: See my answer referencing the [Unlimited weeks in Google Calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-weeks-in-google/kppipnjcfidhlpgckimgaifilmkolokj) Chrome extension

Comment: This stopped working. It seems there is no way to get more than 4 weeks.

Comment: @TomViner that link is broke like SVB

Answer (score 8):

All suggestions posted before 2018, including the Chrome extension "Unlimited weeks", no longer work since Google updated their calendar sometime around early 2018.  So apparently there is no solution for this at this time.

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in the six weeks starting with the current week, there is a trick.

Scroll the little calendar forward a couple months so that no dates in the next 6 weeks show up. Then select all 6 weeks that show up in that calendar (not the dates you're interested in) and click on *Today* at the top, and you will get the current week at the top of the big calendar.

This works for a maximum period of 6 weeks because that's how many weeks are shown in the little calendar. Still, that is two more weeks than are available in the *next 4 weeks* option for the custom view.

Comment: If you don't see the little calendar (top left), it's called the "mini calendar".

Comment: Thank you so much for this - this is the only answer I've seen that works

Comment: This works, thanks, but I've been coming back here a few times to reread the right steps, and this time I saw Jummitus' recent answer. Jummitu's trick is simpler and easier to remember, and allows more than 6 weeks. I won't be coming back here, until g cal team shuffles things around.

Comment: @StephThirion I'd like to try that trick, but I don't have a mouse wheel (or a mouse).

Comment: See my answer referencing the [Unlimited weeks in Google Calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-weeks-in-google/kppipnjcfidhlpgckimgaifilmkolokj) Chrome extension

Comment: This stopped working. It seems there is no way to get more than 4 weeks.

Comment: @maf-soft See the answer by panofish

Comment: I think it's not the right way to write an answer to tell something about other answers @Liam - if an answer doesn't work anymore, it should be directly commented or better edited. Or in case of a web app where it's not possible that there are users using an older version, I would even think of deleting :) - don't know what the rules are.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Week view and choose the week that you want to show on the first row in the 6-Week view, and then switch back to that view.

Answer (score 1):

I made a Google Chrome extension that allows you to show as many weeks as you want. It uses exactly the technique mentioned with the mini calendar, but does this with Javascript mouse events.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-weeks-in-google/kppipnjcfidhlpgckimgaifilmkolokj

Comment: This works well, thanks. It did glitch a little bit on me when I started it up (clicking on "+" made it go from 4 weeks to 2 weeks), but worked smoothly after that. Also it didn't have today on the first week initially, not sure why. Too bad I mostly use Firefox :-/